# Refreshing a browser's cache while developing with gulp

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, gulp

My project's setup uses a combination of python's Flask on the backend which serves a fairly simple javascript React webpage using gulp.

Whether I'm debugging frontend code through Chrome or Firefox, I have to do a hard refresh multiple times before the changes make it to the browser.  I see the gulp console log `Finished 'transform' after N ms` after each save, which leads me to believe it's the browsers fault.

I am not a front end engineer so I'm wondering what more experienced devs use.  Hitting `Cmd+Shift+R` 5-20 times after each save is a little mind bogglingly inefficient.

current gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    size = require('gulp-size'),
    del = require('del'),
    babelify = require('babelify'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');


var compiled_dir = './static/scripts/jsc';
var js_dir = './static/scripts/js';

function handle_error(err) {
    gutil.log(err.message);
    gutil.beep();
    return process.exit(2);
}

gulp.task('transform', function () {
    browserify({ entries: js_dir + '/main.js', debug: true })
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handle_error)
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(compiled_dir));
    browserify({ entries: js_dir + '/userMgmt.js', debug: true })
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handle_error)
        .pipe(source('userMgmt.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(compiled_dir));
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del([compiled_dir], cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('transform');
    gulp.watch(js_dir + "/*", ['transform']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** Use this [gulp-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cache) package to disable cache in development mode. 
This will work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/index.html')

    .pipe(gulp.task('clear', function (done) {
        return cache.clearAll(done);
    });)
    .pipe(usemin({
        js: []
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

If you don't know how to use it, please update your question with gulp config file, I will configure you that.

**Method 2:** Configure your watcher.

```
$ npm install browser-sync --save-dev

var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.watch(['./**/*.{scss,css,html,py,js}'], ['clearCache', browserSync.reload]);

gulp.task('clearCache', function (done) {
   return cache.clearAll(done);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tauqeer.  I've updated my post with the gulpfile.  I tried adding the `.pipe(uncache())` to the 'transform' task but was getting a "Streams not supported" error.

Comment: @LucianThorr can you try this? `gulp.watch(js_dir + "/*", ['transform', 'clearCache', reload]);`

Comment: Where are `'clearCache'` and `reload` imported from?

Comment: Updated my answer with browserSync.reload.

Comment: What about 'clearCache'?  Where is that defined?
This is working better but not perfect:
```gulp.watch(js_dir + "/*", ['transform']).on("change", function (e) {
        return gulp.src(e.path).pipe(uncache()).pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
    })```

Comment: `clearCache ` is just a value, not a variable, How you is it working better and not perfectly, What's the issue you facing now?

Comment: By "not perfectly," I mean I still have to refresh 5 or 6 times to see the changes in the browser.  Better than 10-20 but still not 1 refresh to see new changes.
When I use 'clearCache', I get ```Task 'clearCache' is not in your gulpfile```

Comment: Updated both the solutions please check now, I replaced the `uncache` module with `gulp-cache` and in the second answer, you must add a task, that I added now.

Comment: Method 2 is working much better.  Still not a perfect refresh-per-save but it's only taking 2-3 hard refreshes to see my changes.  I see that 'clearCache' is running everytime I save but Chrome is just very stubborn about clearing its cache.
Thanks Tauqeer for all the patience and help.